# Heroku production issues with Sinatra app (Error R10)

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I followed heroku's instructions on deploying a Sinatra application carefully but something is still going wrong. I am using sinatra-base and sinatra-partial if that makes any difference. I have all the gems declared in the gemfile and myapp.rb

[Gist of my files](https://gist.github.com/jamesfzhang/5758966)

This is what I see on heroku logs

```
2013-06-11T05:09:28.982664+00:00 app[web.1]:    from myapp.rb:49:in `<class:MyApp>'
2013-06-11T05:09:29.148291+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-11 05:09:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-06-11T05:09:29.148613+00:00 app[web.1]: == Sinatra/1.4.0 has taken the stage on 4567 for production with backup from WEBrick
2013-06-11T05:09:29.148759+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-11 05:09:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=4567
2013-06-11T05:09:29.148291+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-11 05:09:29] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-06-11T05:10:26.570140+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2013-06-11T05:10:26.570414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-06-11T05:10:28.018692+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-06-11T05:10:28.033080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

After doing a bit more research on the `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch` error, it may be because of gems taking a long time to load. However, I am only using these gems so I don't know why it's timing out. Locally, it takes about 1 second to start up my application.

Comment: Does your app code try to connect to anything during initialization? Also, since you're alteady adding sinatra gem, you may remove the sinatra-base gem from your Gemfile.

Comment: Also, in your config.ru, it must be `run MyApp` if your app subclasses from `Sinatra::Base`

Comment: What does `myapp.rb` look like?

Comment: Here's a gist of my files. https://gist.github.com/jamesfzhang/5758966

Comment: @Kashyap instead of `run Sinatra::Application`, it should just be `run MyApp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku dynamically assigns the port. You are starting the app on port 4567 when you call the `run!` method in lines 85-97 of myapp.rb. You should be able to remove those three lines and use config.ru to start your app.

It you add the heroku gem to your Gemfile, you can remove the Procfile. Otherwise you should cahnge it start the app via backup:

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

You could also add 'thin' to your Gemfile and use a Procfile like this

```
web: bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RACK_ENV -p $PORT
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the fix. Along with replacing `run Sinatra::Application` with `run MyApp`